# NSMutableArray of NSNumber is nil after adding parsed float

Tags: opencv3.0, objective-c++

I am trying to parse an array of Vectors (from C++'s std::vector) to an NSMutableArray of NSNumber. However, the Vector that I add to the NSNumber array is always nil, even after adding a NSNumber (parsed from std::vector)

In this project, I'm trying to connect the OpenCV Canny Edge Detection Algorithm (C++) to my Swift project. One of their methods returns all the photo's edges as std::vector. So, I'm trying to parse this into an array that is compatible with Swift (using Objective-C++ as the intermediary language). As of right now, it seems that only one line isn't working correctly (as stated above).
I am also a beginner Objective-C++ programmer, so there may be some common errors in the code, which I haven't found.

```
/*Ptr<LineSegmentDetector>*/
cv::Ptr<cv::LineSegmentDetector> ls = cv::createLineSegmentDetector(cv::LSD_REFINE_STD) ;//Creates the line detector (AKA what I called the edge detector)

std::vector<cv::Vec4f> lines_std;

[image convertToMat: &mat];

// Detect the lines
ls->detect(mat, lines_std);

//Swift compatible NSMutableArray to return from this method
NSMutableArray *edgeLines;

printf("currently finding the edge lines");

for (int i = 0; i < lines_std.size(); i ++) {
    NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *vector;

    //Convert from Vec4f to NSNumber
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k ++) {
        [vector addObject: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: (lines_std[i][k])]]; //HERE, I'm parsing each float value in each vector (from std::vector<cv::Vec4f>) and adding it to a NSArray, like a vector
    }

    //Here, I add the vectors to the return NSMutable array
    [edgeLines insertObject:vector atIndex:edgeLines.count];
}

return edgeLines;
```

As stated above, the "vector" variable is always nil, even though I'm adding an NSNumber object to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I hadn't used this line:
    NSMutableArray *vector = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: Add `NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *vector = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` to make your answer clear.